# Process Dynamically Created Laravel Queue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-queue

I am using Laravel Queues to process jobs for users, in background. For each user i have a separate queue like:

```
Process::withChain(
                            [
                                new Step1(),
                                new Step2()
                            ]
                        )->dispatch()->allOnQueue($user)->delay(now()->addMinutes(1));
```

now the issue is i dont know how i can dynamically process these queues by issuing following command

```
artisan queue:work --tries=3 --daemon --queue=<user_name>
```

any comments/suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom artisan command and then in your `handle()` method:

```
$queueName = ... // put your logic here
$this->call('queue:work', [
    '--tries' => 3, '--queue' => $queueName
]);
```

Comment: thanks for your time. As per my understanding `handle` method is called when there is a queue listener running and processing jobs. What if there is no queue listener running and a new job is inserted on a queue? Hope i am clear in explaining what i am trying to achieve :)

Comment: I am bit confused. The `handle()` method I was mentioning is inside your custom Artisan Command, see https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#writing-commands.

Anyway for what you are asking, the job is put in the queue and if there is not listener (i.e queue worker) it just stays there indefinitely

Comment: thats what i am trying to achieve, to start a queue listener dynamically. Thanks for your input :)

Comment: Maybe you can add  --stop-when-empty because if you open 100 jobs they will stay open in the processes of your server